# Different outputs from Clip_management and ExtractByMask

Tags: arcpy, clip, extract-by-mask

I have a question about clipping a part from a raster according to the extent of a polygon. 
Should `Clip_management` and `ExtractByMask` create the same results if I set the "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT" option for *Clip* and the "snapRaster" option for *Extract by Mask* (to avoid any resampling)?

```
arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "#", outraster, "in_memory\shape_lyr", "-9999", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

vs

```
arcpy.env.snapRaster = raster
outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(raster, "in_memory\shape_lyr")
outExtractByMask.save(outraster)
```

If yes, why my two outputs still differ? See photo:

[image: Results]

I can analyse that the method: `Clip_management` produced 3 values more than `ExtractByMask` (comparing two attribute tables) but could not identify where exactly.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I just found one of the 3 pixels (red), that was made by using `Clip_management` but not `ExtractByMask`. It's driving me crazy.
[image: The red one was created using <code>Clip_management</code>]

EDIT2: Im using ArcGis 10.4.1.
After a long time having no answer, I decided for myself that Extract By Mask is more accurate than Clip management!

Comment: Is the difference in fifth digit after decimal point so meaningful, while min is 4 and max is 39?

Comment: Actually not, but I wonder should'nt it be the same?

Comment: Play with snap raster and env. Extent

Comment: @Felix. I 've done already. No changes.

Comment: Well, convert polygon to raster to find which one is wrong. Please post the result. I'd say the grey answer is more accurate.

Comment: As far as I can see, Clip Management creates some false pixels in comparison to extract by mask. That's why I will use extract by mask. I think it is a bug in Arcgis and have reported it to the support. Lets see if they have any answers for this.

But if anybody has an idea, you are very welcome.

Comment: @PDUY Please post that as an answer - it is fine and encouraged  to self-answer.